# How can I tell `./gradlew clean` to also delete out folders produces by IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

As in the title, how can I tell `./gradlew clean` to also delete out folders produces by IntelliJ ? It seems that IntelliJ uses this directory for execution context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even if it's possible to use the [`delete`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#delete(java.lang.Object...)) method of the `Project` instance in a `doLast` closure, you should actually use the [`delete`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Delete.html#delete(java.lang.Object...)) method of the [`Delete`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete.html) task:

```
clean {
    delete 'out'     // interpreted relative to the project directory
}
```